# Some memcahe functions are not working

Tags: php, memcached

I am using below code

```
$this->memcache = new Memcache();
$this->memcache->connect('127.0.0.1', 11211) or die("Could not connect");
$this->memcache->getExtendedStats('slabs');
```

this is throwing below error

Call to undefined method Memcache::getExtendedStats()

```
$this->memcache->getVersion()
```

Call to undefined method Memcache::getVersion()

But when I use some other function like set, get it works fine

I have need to get all slabs so please help me to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a know bug.
The issue seems to because there are two functions one for `memcached` (getstats) and the other for `memcache` (getExtendedStats).

You can go through this [link](https://www.drupal.org/node/856276) for more details. The patch provided seems to work.